# Two jQuery events are not syncronized

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to apply **slideDown** and **slideUp** events.

I have a **checkbox** and two **div** (`myDiv1` and `myDiv2`). The checkbox activates both divs to slide down or slide up. So both must be up or down (not one down and the other up).

But if I click two times quickly on the checkbox before one div finished sliding down, the other div slides up. So then one div is up and the other is down.

```
$("#myCheckbox").click(function() {
    if ($("#myCheckbox").is(":checked")) { // Now is checked.
        $.when($("#myDiv2").slideDown(slow)).done(function() {
            $("#myDiv1").slideDown(slow);
        });
    }
    else { // Now is unchecked.
        $.when($("#myDiv2").slideUp(slow)).done(function() {
            $("#myDiv1").slideUp(slow))
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code

Comment: Maybe try it without the "when", just slide down or up and then .done

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1. Disable the checkbox or stop the code from executing if those animations are currently running

Answer 2. Have a queue built in for each animation, so, instead of calling slideUp or slideDown directly on anything you instead would add "slideUp" or "slideDown" to an array to act as a queue. Have the queue check itself and run the needed slideUp or slideDown when needed using some kind of gameloop or timing system.

Answer 3. If the function is currently running then add a 0.1 second delay then check if it's currently running, keep doing that until it isn't currently running, then execute. If it's currently running and a second execution is currently checking for when it can run, then cancel the second execution. Aka, if they triple click quickly, it'll only run the first animation as the 2nd and 3rd clicks will cancel each other out

I'll add some code if it helps